# React Navigation 5 createMaterialTopTabNavigator Disable Swipe depending on screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm using react navigation 5 with createMaterialTopTabNavigator, I have everything working however I realized that I'd like to prevent swipe depending on the screen.

```
const Swiper = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const Tabs = () => {
  return (
    <Swiper.Navigator
      tabBar={(props) => null}
      initialRouteName="Page1"
      swipeEnabled={false}
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Swiper.Screen name="Page1" component={Page1} />
      <Swiper.Screen name="Page2" component={Page2} />
    </Swiper.Navigator>
  );
};
```

So this disabled the swipe action for everything, however I'd like to be able to swipe from page1 to page2, but not from page2 to page1. I tried putting swipeEnabled in the screen but that didn't work. Like this:

```
const Tabs = () => {
  return (
    <Swiper.Navigator
      tabBar={(props) => null}
      initialRouteName="Page1"
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Swiper.Screen name="Page1" component={Page1} />
      <Swiper.Screen name="Page2" swipeEnabled={false} component={Page2} />
    </Swiper.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BasvanderLinden yup, thanks! Although I do get a warning when trying it in my setup "Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component"

Comment: @BasvanderLinden my createMaterialTopTabNavigator is nested inside another stack navigator, how would I go about supporting this? When I try the useState in my const Tabs I get the above warning